# Geektool and tail follow

Tags: macos, unix, cron, system, tail

I have this LIVE list of formatted urls captured from system log and outputted to a different log file.

> tail -F /var/log/system.log | grep --line-buffered "query=" | sed -le "s/.*query=//" | sed -le "s/\"//g" | sed -le "s/.$/ /" >> /tmp/urls.log

How do I start this automatically like cronjob but runs only once on each logon.

raw log file is like this:

> x yy zzz query="www.yahoo.com."

Struggling all evening over this! thanks!

Comment: ignore the title saying "GeekTool".

Comment: Why whould your run it at login ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a LaunchAgent should work. Create a .plist file with the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>label</key>
        <string>name you want to give it</string>

        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
          <array>
            <string>/bin/bash</string>
            <string>/path/to/your/script.sh</string>
          </array>       


         <key>RunAtLoad</key>
         <true/>

        <key>OnDemand</key>
        <false/>

        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Save this file to `~/Library/LaunchAgents`. You will then need to load the launchagent by doing `launchctl load -wF /path/to/launch.plist`. To make sure it's loaded correctly check to see whether it's in here the output of `launchctl list`.

For more information you can look at [Apple Developer 1](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) and [Apple Developer 2](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html)

Comment: i looks like the right solution. I will try this today. thanks!